# WordCloud OSError: cannot open resource

Tags: python

I try to use chinese font, but the result shows ( OSError: cannot open resource )
I know WordCloud doesn't support chinese,but I refer to the answers on other networkstry
,set to the built-in chinese font in my computer,it still not feasible.
How can I solve it?

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


text = " ".join(review for review in count_list)
font_path = 'C:\windows\Fonts\simsun.ttc'
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=1200, height=600, max_font_size=200, max_words=200, background_color="black", 
                      font_path=font_path, colormap="Dark2").generate(text)
plt.figure(dpi=600)
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

This is the error message

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-4ba7308fea35> in <module>()
      7 # back_color = imageio.imread("./taiwan.png")
      8 wordcloud = WordCloud(width=1200, height=600, max_font_size=200, max_words=200, background_color="black", 
----> 9                       font_path=font_path, colormap="Dark2").generate(text)
     10 plt.figure(dpi=600)
     11 plt.imshow(wordcloud)

OSError: cannot open resource
```

Comment: pls check the path of `simsun.ttc` , the script could not find the file. once it finds the path and can't understand you will get some different error.

Comment: as per the documentation, the supported formats are `OTF or TTF` so try to download in that format otherwise you will get error like `OSError: unknown file format`. i tried with `dfhei1b-gb.TTF` [from](http://www.font-club.com/font-category/Chinese_6.html) and worked okay(no errors)

Comment: @simpleApp I try to use dfhei1b-gb.TTF , it show me this

`File "<ipython-input-145-5a73dc42c959>", line 6
    font_path = '‪C:\Users\s4102\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\DFHei1BGB.ttf'
               ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 12-13: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

Comment: pls post some data from `text` so we can try.

Comment: the text and font(dfhei1b-gb) do not seem to be compatible. I am not getting any text on the word cloud although with no errors.

Comment: @simpleApp I have tried many Chinese fonts myself, but the problem seems to be stuck, OSError: cannot open resource, although the font path is correct.

Comment: not sure if this is an access issue. would you put font and script in the same folder, and then try?

Comment: @simpleApp I didn't write it in a general python environment.I used google colab to make the script.I tried putting the script and the font in the same folder, but the result was the same.

Comment: @simpleApp Thanks you for your help, I have solved my problem, I did put the font and script in the same folder, but my path setting was wrong, resulting in Error